# How to publish your android studio apk on internet for free?

Tags: android, publish

I have finished my project and I want to publish it on the internet. I have tried Google Playstore as well as different publishers, but I need to pay 25$ for a licence. Is there any free alternative.

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: there are various alternative is available..they provide a link of your app(APK) for download like https://www.diawi.com/

Comment: @Nice umang I tried using diawi.com but I dont know why when i drop my app-debug.apk and when i try to download on other phones it doesent work

Comment: you mean not installed successfully m i right??

Comment: I fixed it, it was about sdk bcs I had oreo and it was meant for Q. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Nice umang said diawi.com did wonders

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of alternatives . I would recommend Amazon app store. But Google's play store is worth it. Since it's just one time payment unlike apple store